# sip REGISTER response with nat ip

Tags: sip, voip

I am observed I am getting changed contact(local ip replaced with nat ip) in 200 ok REGISTER response. And sure i am not behind SIP-ALG, because rport in via also having the same address.

How to handle when contact is changed in the request, is there any SIP RFC discussed about this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. Can you add SIP traces and rephrase a little bit your problem so we can help you more?

Answer (score 0):

Could be better if you are clear with your question.
But hope the below rport functionality might help.

Consider an example. A client sends an INVITE which looks like:

INVITE sip:user@domain SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.1.1.1:4540;rport

This INVITE is sent with a source port of 4540 and source IP of 10.1.1.1. The request is natted, so that the source IP appears as 68.44.20.1 and the source port as 9988. This is received at a proxy.The proxy forwards the request, but not before appending a value to the rport parameter in the proxied request:

INVITE sip:user@domain2 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP proxy.domain.com
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.1.1.1:4540;received=68.44.20.1;rport=9988

This request generates a response, which arrives at the proxy:

SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP proxy.domain.com
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.1.1.1:4540;received=68.44.20.1;rport=9988

The proxy strips its top Via, and then examines the next one. It con-
tains both a received param, and an rport. The result is that the
follow response is sent to IP address 68.44.20.1, port 9988:

SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.1.1.1:4540;received=68.44.20.1;rport=9988

The NAT rewrites the destination address of this packet back to IP
10.1.1.1, port 4540, and is received by the client.

You can refer to the SIP NAT RFCs listed below
https://www.ietf.org/proceedings/52/I-D/draft-ietf-sip-nat-01.txt
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6314#section-4.1.1